# SSDs compatible with 15'' 2014 MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I've to change the SSD of my MacBook Pro, and before purchasing I want to be sure of choosing the right components:

SSD: [Crucial P1 1TB](https://www.amazon.it/Crucial-CT1000P1SSD8-Interno-NAND-PCIe/dp/B07J2Q4SWZ/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_it_IT=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=FTA0YWPB4V2&keywords=crucial%20p1&qid=1576614331&s=pc&sprefix=crucial%20p1%2Caps%2C229&sr=1-1)

SSD-adaptor: [SSD M2 adapter](https://www.amazon.it/Eboxer-interfaccia-Supporto-Dimensioni-Adattatore/dp/B07FLPKYZX/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_it_IT=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&keywords=eboxer%20ssd%20m2%20adapter&qid=1576614502&s=pc&sr=1-1)

How can I determine if these are compatible with my 2014 15” MacBook Pro?